# find then ln then chown then chmod

Tags: bash

This is like what I use (ALOT MORE VARIABLES). I'm now trying to chown user:user {}, then chmod 640 {}, all after the hard link is created, on the hard link. But nothing that I try seems to work.

```
find . -name "test" -exec ln {} /path/ \;
```

So like:

```
find . -name "test" -exec ln {} /path/ | chown user:user /path/{} | chmod 640 /path/{} \;
```

Comment: This: `find . -name "test" -exec ln {} /path/ \; -exec chown user:user /path/{} \; -exec chmod 640 /path/{} \;` (will only work from current dir).

Comment: It doesn't matter if you chmod/chown the original or new link, they share permissions and owners.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm trying to find then move, then change permissions. Do you have a better way? Thanks for your input!

Comment: @thatotherguy Really?? HMM That actually makes sense.

Comment: @DavidCuster A better way than the working command they gave you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but hardlinks to directories are not allowed on *nix as far as I know so I suppose you want a symbolic link and you seem to have wanted the link to land in /path from the way you coded the ownership and permission changes:

`sudo find . -name "test" -exec sh -c "ln -s /path/ /path/{}; chown user:user /path/{}; chmod 640 /path/{}" \;`